# Base64 encodeBytes - out of memory exception

Tags: android

I ma trying to upload a picture from android to remote server. Everything is working is fine except for large photos. I am getting "memory out of exception" at Base64.encodeBytes() methos. Here is the code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

Can you guys please help me solving this issue ? I have tried to solve this issue by insampling the bitmap before, and it works but it scales down the bitmap and i always want to upload pictures in its original size.

Thanks.

Comment: PNG is a lossless format so it doesn't use the quality setting. Should use JPEG instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution regarding uploading exact original size of image to server:

```
public static void upload(String pathToOurFile, String serverUrl){
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String urlServer = serverUrl;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
    }
}
```

Comment: can this method use on webview posturl?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before for large images...I have just scaled bitmap before converting it to Base64... you can use it as following...

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //compress to which format you want.
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

Comment: but its scaling the bimap rite ?? and i want to upload it in its original image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these statements:

> 1- I ma trying to upload a picture from android to remote server.
>
> 2- but its scaling the bimap rite ?? and i want to upload it in its
>   original image.

I'm going to assume any answer will do as long as the solution helps you upload files to a server from android application and keeps the original image.

Solution - Remove the compression out of the tutorial below and it should send you on your way.

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

**Avoid Base64.encodeBytes() for large image files.**

Answer (score -1):

you can try to change the quality parameter of compress like i have just given to 10 & it will work fine for large image also.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, stream); 
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

Comment: i'l give it a try. Thnx for response.

Comment: is this what is imported in your project import android.util.Base64; if yes then try to use the following url & import that Base64.java in your project & then check. http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.in/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

Comment: no i m not using android.util.Base64; i downloaded from here http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Comment: PNG is a lossless format so it doesn't use the quality setting. Should use JPEG instead