# android java OutOfMemoryError exception when sending huge string

Tags: java, image, connection

I have android application , which turns an image to base64 string. I want to send this string to the server using web service. I am using REST web service by Jersey.

I can send and receive from the server. I can do any thing between android and server.

Now:

when i put the image in the string I got exceptoin :

```
05-31 12:30:01.641: E/AndroidRuntime(19194): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

It is obvious that is because the `base64` string is large, but how to solve that pelase?

The class for connection to server is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class Client {

    private String server;

    public Client(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    private String getBase() {
        return server;
    }

    public String getBaseURI(String str) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(getBase() + str);
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            result = getResult(response).toString();
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return result;
    }
 private StringBuilder getResult(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())), 1024);
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) 
                result.append(output);

            return result;      
      }
}
```

Then simply I use that class like this:

```
Client client = new Client("http://192.168.55.1:8080/test2/eattel/");
            String r = client.getBaseURI("image/" + "D");
```

**It seems that I have to put the `huge string` in `getRequest` or in the `httpClient`**  but I dont know how.

any help please

**Maybe because I am using HttpGet not HttpPost** ?

Comment: can you send it in multiple parts since it is a string.

Comment: I prefer sending it one part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287640/1075066